# Is there any way to install the provisioning profile on iOS device without Xcode to iTunes?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

My enterprise application is having more than 1000 users. And my Provisioning profile got expired 3 4 days before. After the expiration the existing users start facing the problem, their app is not open.

When I debug his I found that the provisioning profile is not present on their device. And on logs I found that "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found".

When I manually add Provisioning profile on one user's device the application start work perfectly.

So by following this step I try to install that provisioning profile on users device by uploading that provisioning profile on server and send that link to all the users. But now some of users those who have iOS version 9.0 and later said to me that on there iPhone 
After clicking on that provisioning profile link the Settings > General > profile screen automatically open (Screen Shot Added)

[Screen shot after click on provisioning link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjT0I.jpg)

and provisioning profile is not install and problem with application remains as it is.

Please tell me the solution for this.

Its an production issue please help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you all the way - what do you mean by saying - "Installed provision profile on device" ? In order to get the provision profile onto their device you should re-codesign the app using the new valid provision profile and then ask users to install the app.

Comment: Thanks Roy Yes this is the only way by re-codesign the app using new valid provisioning profile and then tell all the 1000+ users to download and install the new version of app. This is the solution which I found till now

Answer (score 0):

After searching on web I found that its not possible to add new provisioning profile into the device without creating a new build and install that build into the device. This is the only way you can renew the provisioning profile.